# I'm not able to create 10 files with following batch code

Tags: batch-file

Following is the code in which I want to create 10 files if the counter reach 10 but the comparison is not working am I missing something or am I doing something wrong? It creates only one file and prints as following in that one file

> 10 == 0 set

```
@echo off
set limit=10
set count=0
:start
set count = %count% + 1
echo %limit% == %count% set > YouAreAnIdiot%random%.txt
if %count%==%limit% 
    exit 0
else 
    goto start
```

Comment: Read the help for the SET command. You are missing a very specific option.

Comment: And as Stephan has pointed out your IF ELSE command is incorrect. Again the help file for the IF command shows you exactly how to do an IF ELSE command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two errors in one line: `set count = %count% + 1`:

a) the space between `count` and `=` is part of your variable name. (It would be `%count %`)

b) to calculate with `set`, you need the `/a` parameter:

```
set /a count=%count% + 1
```

Surprisingly, `set /a` doesn't care for the additional space, but get used to the syntax without spaces around the `=` - this keeps life simple.

`set /a` doesn't need the percent signs with variables, so `set /a count=count+1` also works.

There is a short form to do that:

```
set /a count+=1
```

Also your `if` statement will not work. The complete construct has to be on one (logical) line:

```
if %count%==%limit% (
    exit 0
) else ( 
    goto start
)
```

(note the spaces around the parantheses - they are critical)